# small C program working

Tags: c

> Practice.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char a;

  printf("\nEnter Anything = ");
  scanf("%c",&a);                  <Line 1>

  printf("\n%d",a);
  printf("\n%c",a);
}

Output 1 : Enter Character = 5

           53
           5
Output 2 : Enter Character = a

           97
           a
```

This program gets executed exactly by the book.

> New.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  char a;

  printf("\nEnter Character = ");
  scanf("%d",&a);                <Line 1>

  printf("\n%d",a);
  printf("\n%c",a);
}

Output 1 : Enter Character = 5

           5
           ♣
Output 2 : Enter Character = a

           0
```

This is the same program as `Practice.c` with minor change in it. It is not a question but I mistakenly typed `%d` instead of `%c` in the line denoted by `Line 1` of the program. This mistake of mine produced 2 very different outputs. What is the exact reason behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below ASCII `32`, all are non-printable characters. In second code you are reading an `int` and then trying to print the equivalent character which is non-printable.

For the second input `a`, `scanf` doesn't read this character and leave it in the buffer because it expects an integer not a character. The variable `a` is uninitialized and you are now accessing an uninitialized variable. This invokes **undefined behavior**.

Answer (score 1):

The character data type is having size 1 byte, whereas integer is usually 4 bytes. Here you have tried to read into a character variable an integer. There is not enough storage to handle this properly. The result depends on whether your architecture supports little endian or big endian notation.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `%c` the input is taken as character and stored its ASCII value.

When you use `%d` the input is taken as integer.

When you print with `%c`, it tries to print ASCII char at given value.

When you print with `%d`, it tries to print the number.

Answer (score 1):

*What really happened in your NEW program is*

`scanf("%d",&a);`

Format specifier while reading is given as an integer %d ,so the compiler assumes the input value as integer even though it is stored in char variable, so the value of variable will be
 a  = 0x05         which is an integer 5

```
  printf("\n%d",a);
```

printing variable a as integer prints 5 on output

```
  printf("\n%c",a);
```

**I think you know that while reading a digit as a character(using %c) it's ASCII value is stored (for eg:    `scanf("%c",&a));` and you enter *a* as 5, the value stored in the variable *a* is *a*=0x35 in hex ,or 53 as integer representation**

**printing variable as character-> since 0x05 is not character or digit in ASCII value it prints the special character on the output**

*for about ASCII table refer : http://www.asciitable.com/*